# how to split the screen in glut codeblocks for multiplayer in c

Tags: c, 3d, codeblocks, glut, multiplayer

I have a project that requires me to make a game of two players at the same time while controlling the game characters via the keyboard and the mouse. To start, I need to know how to separate the screen so that the game is repeated in two halves with the difference in scores and other things

I searched a lot, but I did not find anything in the C language, so I hope someone can help me here

note:

-The game must be in 3D

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You will likely need a second viewport.